# Null Pointer Exception in Rock, Paper, Scissors program

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, compiler-errors

I wanted to lead this question by letting everyone know that this is my first time on stack overflow so if I do not conform to question-asking standards please let me know.

I'm making a program that plays Rock, Paper, Scissors with you, and right as I was approaching the back end of the project this error came up:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
  at RockPaperScissors.getPlayerThrow(RockPaperScissors.java:93)
  at RockPaperScissors.main(RockPaperScissors.java:26)
```

I'm not sure where I would be using null, but thats what you're here for.

Here is the entire project compiled as it currently is:

```
public class RockPaperScissors {
//sets the constants
static final int ROCK = 1;
static final int PAPER = 2;
static final int SCISSORS = 3;

//creates some variables
static int playerThrow, computerThrow, result, timesPlayed, playerWins, computerWins;
static String playAgain;
static Scanner fru;

/*
 * The Results
 * 0 = tie
 * 1 = Player win
 * 2 = Computer win
*/

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //this do while loop is the whole game
    do {
        //decides the throws of the players
        playerThrow = getPlayerThrow();
        computerThrow = (int)(Math.random() * 3 + 1);

        switch(playerThrow) {
        //compares and displays the computer and player
        //choices if the player chooses rock
        case ROCK:
            switch(computerThrow) {
            case ROCK:
                result = 0;
                System.out.println("You threw rock and the computer threw rock!");
                break;
            case PAPER:
                result = 2;
                System.out.println("You threw rock and the computer threw paper!");
                break;
            case SCISSORS:
                result = 1;
                System.out.println("You threw rock and the computer threw scissors!");
                break;
            }   break;
        //compares and displays the computer and player
        //choices if the player throws paper
        case PAPER:
            switch(computerThrow) {
            case ROCK:
                result = 1;
                System.out.println("You threw paper and the computer threw rock!");
                break;
            case PAPER:
                result = 2;
                System.out.println("You threw paper and the computer threw paper!");
                break;
            case SCISSORS:
                result = 3;
                System.out.println("You threw paper and the computer threw scissors!");
                break;
            }   break;
        //compares and displays the computer and player
        //choices if the player throws scissors
        case SCISSORS:
            switch(computerThrow) {
            case ROCK:
                result = 2;
                System.out.println("You threw scissors and the computer threw rock!");
                break;
            case PAPER:
                result = 1;
                System.out.println("You threw scissors and the computer threw paper!");
                break;
            case SCISSORS:
                result = 0;
                System.out.print("You threw scissors and the computer threw scissors!");
                break;
            }   break;
        }
        timesPlayed ++;

        // will compare and decide the winner of the two players
        finish();

    } while (timesPlayed < 3);
}

public static int getPlayerThrow() {
    //prompts weapon choice and stores said choice
    System.out.println("Choose your weapon of choice:\n(1 for rock, 2 for paper, 3 for scissors)");
    int choice = fru.nextInt();

    //checks for validity and returns the choice
    if (choice != 1 && choice != 2 && choice != 3) {
        System.out.print("Not a valid input!\n Please try again: ");
        choice = fru.nextInt();
    }

    return choice;
}

//compares and decides the winner of the two players
public static void finish() {
    //displays the winner of the round accourding to aforementioned possible results
    switch(result) {
    case 0:
        System.out.println("Its a tie!"); break;
    case 1:
        System.out.println("You are victorious! Man over machine!");
         playerWins++; break;
    case 2:
        System.out.println("The computer has taken the round! Technological singularity approaches!");
        computerWins++; break;
    }

    //cheks if the match is over and displays messages accordingly
    switch(timesPlayed) {
    case 1: break;
    case 2:
        if (playerWins == 2 || computerWins == 2) {
            if (playerWins == 2) {
                System.out.println("You win the match! Congratulations!\nWould you like to play another match?\n(y for yes, n for no)");
                timesPlayed = 5;
                playAgain = fru.nextLine();

                //checks for validity
                if (playAgain != "y" || playAgain != "n") {
                    System.out.print("Not a valid input!\n Please try again: ");
                    playAgain = fru.nextLine();
                }
            }
            else if (computerWins == 2) {
                System.out.println("The computer wins the match!\nPlay again! I know you can beat it.\n(y for yes, n for no)");
                timesPlayed = 5;
                playAgain = fru.nextLine();

                //checks for validity
                if (playAgain != "y" || playAgain != "n") {
                    System.out.print("Not a valid input!\n Please try again: ");
                    playAgain = fru.nextLine();
                }
            }
        } break;
    //will happen for any amount of times played over 2
    default:
        if (playerWins == 2) {
            System.out.println("You win the match! Congratulations!\nWould you like to play another match?\n(y for yes, n for no)");
            playAgain = fru.nextLine();

            //checks for validity
            if (playAgain != "y" || playAgain != "n") {
                System.out.print("Not a valid input!\n Please try again: ");
                playAgain = fru.nextLine();
            }
        }
        else if (computerWins == 2) {
            System.out.println("The computer wins the match!\nPlay again! I know you can beat it.\n(y for yes, n for no)");
            playAgain = fru.nextLine();

            //checks for validity
            if (playAgain != "y" || playAgain != "n") {
                System.out.print("Not a valid input!\n Please try again: ");
                playAgain = fru.nextLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

I understand neither what the error means nor where it comes from. The only information that I have about it comes from skimming google for the error, but it is tough when the questions asked or examples posted are not specific to my project. I have taken multiple steps towards fixing it but none of them seem to do anything.

This could be a complex coding problem or a single character that I have missed, but any and all help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: _but thats what you're here for_ ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see plenty of places where you *use* the `fru` scanner but absolutely none where you actually initialise it. What you have basically boils down to:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test {
    static Scanner fru;
    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        int x = fru.nextInt();
        System.out.println(x+1);
    }
}
```

and, when you run that, you'll see the exception. You'll need to do something like:

```
fru = new Scanner(System.in);
```

before you attempt to do any scanning. Until you do that, trying to dereference it will cause the exception you're getting. In other words, something like:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test {
    static Scanner fru;
    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        fru = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = fru.nextInt();
        System.out.println(x+1);
    }
}
```

which runs successfully.

---

In terms of finding these problems in future, you would do well to look at the error message you're actually getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
  at RockPaperScissors.getPlayerThrow(RockPaperScissors.java:93)
  at RockPaperScissors.main(RockPaperScissors.java:26)
```

Despite the fact your error message doesn't *quite* match your code (line numbers are off by three), examining the stack trace to track down where and what the errors are is a vital skill.

In this case, it's the line:

```
int choice = fru.nextInt();
```

and you would therefore assume it's because `fru` has not been set correctly. From there, it a matter of tracking back to where you actually set `fru` to something useful. In this particular case, that doesn't exist so it's relatively easy to figure out.

Comment: To the downvoter, your definition of "not useful" appears to be vastly different to mine. This is the *exact* problem the asker has with their code.